# Quasi-symmetric generalizations of classical symmetric functions

Tags: reference-request, hopf-algebras, symmetric-functions

I am looking for quasi-symmetric versions of the classical $e_\lambda$ and $h_\lambda$ (the elementary and complete homogeneous symmetric functions). *Is there some reference for this?*

I am aware of at least four quasi-symmetric generalizations of Schur polynomials:

- Extended Schur (Assaf, Searles)
- Quasi-symmetric Schur (Haglund et al)
- Young quasi-symmetric Schur
- Dual Immaculate functions

There are also [two quasi-symmetric power-sums](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.11613) which I know of.

I have defined a non-symmetric extension of the elementary symmetric functions, (as a certain specialization of non-symmetric Macdonald polynomials), and this can perhaps be turned into some quasi-symmetric version. However, I have not yet managed to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I sent an email to Stephanie van Willigenburg,
and she suggested [the following reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.2201.pdf), which contains such generalizations.